# Is there a way to convert "Test Results Analyzer" or "Test Result" Jenkins plugins reports to beautiful HTML

Tags: html, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, test-results

Is there a way to covert "Test Results Analyzer" or "Test Result" Jenkins plugins reports to beautiful HTML.

I want to share the report only and did not want anyone to login or see reports via Jenkins UI.